# How can I increase ansible speed?

Tags: ansible

I have 1000 servers. when I run ansible the gathering fact take alot of time.
does any one have solution?
Can I store gather facts to a file then read from it?

the second problem is that at first I can ssh to 1000 servers with my key but after a time it does not accept my key and I should open the new session so I run ansible 10 servers by 10 servers.
What should I do?

Comment: What happened with the 1M connections question?

Comment: they vote to close it so I delete it

Answer (score 1):

Ansible supports a number of [cache plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html) that you can use to persist your facts so that they don't need to be gathered every time.

For example, add the following to your `ansible.cfg` to cache as JSON files in a `.facts` directory:

```
[defaults]
gathering = smart
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = ./.facts
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
```

The `fact_caching_timeout` settings controls how long cached information is considered valid. It's important to keep this in mind: for example, if you add a new network interface to your host, it won't show up in ansible facts until either (a) the previously cached information expires or (b) you force fact gathering explicitly.

Comment: Also add "fact_caching_timeout = 86400" (expire time in seconds), your time might vary.

Comment: @A.Scherbaum thanks, good catch. I'll add that to the answer.